# How do you create an implementation of abstract Function1 trait

Tags: scala

Scala newbie here. I'm a lot confused about why the below code throws an exception.  I know `Function1[Int, Int]` has an abstract `apply` method of type `Int => Int` that needs to be defined.  Doesn't the below `oddfunc` do that?   Why doesn't `x(3)` call the concrete `apply` method defined in `oddfunc`?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait oddfunc extends Function1[Int,Int] {
 | def apply(a: Int): Int = a+3
 | }
defined trait oddfunc

scala> val x = new oddfunc{}
x: oddfunc = <function1>

scala> x(3)
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $anon$1.apply$mcII$sp(I)I
  at oddfunc$class.apply(<console>:8)
  at $anon$1.apply(<console>:8)
  ... 43 elided
```

Comment: That's very strange. On visual inspection, your code seems fine. I cut-and-pasted your exact code into my REPL and it worked perfectly, as expected.

Comment: Maybe it's an environment thing. Which version of scala are you on?  Java?

Comment: 2.11.0 and 1.7.0_25. But your example is mundane enough that it should really work anywhere.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it is a compiler bug? If you replace `trait` with `class` your code works fine on my machine. If I use `trait` I get the same error.

Comment: I ran your code with Scala code runner version 2.11.4 and Java version 1.7.0_60 on Yosemite and it does work perfectly fine!

Comment: I appreciate the responses.  So helpful.  I thought it was my not understanding Scala but it was a compiler issue.  2.11.5 has the issue 2.11.4 does not.

Answer (score 2):

This does seem like a bug which was introduced into the Scala compiler between 2.11.4 and 2.11.5.  I downgraded to Scala 2.11.4 to see if that fixed it and it did.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait oddfunc extends Function1[Int,Int] {
     | def apply(a: Int): Int = a+3
     | }
defined trait oddfunc

scala> val x=new oddfunc{}
x: oddfunc = <function1>

scala> x(3)
res0: Int = 6
```